# React flow selecting top edge selects bottom edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

**Documentation**: https://reactflow.dev/docs/api/nodes/

**Example from documentation**: https://reactflow.dev/examples/custom-node/

**Steps to reproduce bug**:

1. Move any node to around by dragging and dropping
2. Select the top edge handle of the node you just moved around
3. Drag the edge out, and notice how the bottom edge is selected not the top edge

**Expected behaviour**: in step 3, the top edge should be dragged out not the bottom edge

**Code sandbox**: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-flow-forked-xebwl?file=/src/App.tsx

I followed exactly as the documentation and example, yet my implementation has a strange tendency to pick up the bottom edge no matter which edge I select. This issue has not been raised in react-flow's official github issue page, so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong. Can someone figure out why this behaviour is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer by removing randomID to keep regenerating due to re-renders. Answer came from react-flow founder Moritz himself:

"you need to remove the randomID part. With this the id changes on every re-render. You could give your nodes ids and then use these ids inside the node as a prefix for the handle ids: ${nodeid}_bottom . If all handles are sources you also need to set connectionMode="loose" in order to connect sources with sources."